# Setting up a Keras model get the correct output tensor shape of an embedded text, LSTM, autoencoder

Tags: tensorflow, keras, lstm, autoencoder, word-embedding

I'm trying to put together an LSTM autoencoder where the layers (and shapes returned) are:

Embedding -> LSTM -> RepeatVector -> LSTM -> TimeDistributed(Dense).

[6, 18, 8] -> [6, 64] -> [6, 18, 64] -> [6, 18, 64] -> [6, 18, 1]

The last layer is where I'm running into problems and cannot seem to find an answer online. I'm looking for something that would return the same dimensions as the Embedding layer (since I'm trying to make an autoencoder) where I can *undo* the embedding to get the predicted sequence of words back. Maybe I'm misunderstanding something here..?

Below is an example of what I've tried.

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Embedding, LSTM, Dense, RepeatVector, TimeDistributed

dummy_docs = [
    "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.",
    "Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.",
    "When an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.",
    "It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.",
    "It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages.",
    "More recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum."
]

tokenizer = Tokenizer(
    num_words=None,
    filters='!"#$%&()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~\t\n',
    lower=True,
    split=" ",
    oov_token="<OOV>"
)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(dummy_docs)

sequences = pad_sequences(
    tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(dummy_docs),
    padding='post'
)

model = Sequential(
    [
        Embedding(
            input_dim=len(tokenizer.word_index) + 1,
            output_dim=8,
            input_shape=(sequences.shape[1],)
        ),
        LSTM(8, activation='tanh'), # return_sequences..?
        RepeatVector(sequences.shape[1]),
        LSTM(8, activation='tanh', return_sequences=True), # return_sequences..?
        TimeDistributed(Dense(1))
    ]
)

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
model.fit(sequences, sequences, epochs=30, batch_size=1)

y = model.predict(sequences)
```

When I run the fitted model on the `sequences` to obtain a prediction, I'm expecting a 6x18 matrix but I get a single vector of length 18. I'm thinking `Dense(1)` needs to be something else, but anything other than `1` causes mismacthes in the tensor shapes and then the whole model fails. Should I rather be trying a one-hot-encoding input here? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Thanks @MarcoCerliani. I will try what you mentioned. You say the approach is strange. How would you approach it? My actual goal is to clean up dirty text data by using somthing like a denoising autoencoder. I'm just trying to get to a basic autoencoder for text data at the moment and then I'll try to figure out the denoising part when I get there.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to remove the `TimeDistirbuted` layer from the model and use the embedding dimension in the final `Dense()` layer.

Also, I moved the details of the `Embedding` layer outside of `Sequential` to use the same embedding details to get the `y` for `model.fit(X, y, ...)`.
What remains now is to work the predicted embeddings back to the original word sequences, but that is outside of the scope of the original question.

Note, this is not intended for use on sentences, but to use to (hopefully) clean text data (names) where different users entered the same site name in different ways, so regex is not an option because there is no fixed pattern to follow. Some work is still needed to get to the final solution.

Below is the updated section of the code.

```
sequences = pad_sequences(
    tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(dummy_docs),
    padding='post'
)

embedding_dim = 8
embedding_layer = Embedding(
    input_dim=len(tokenizer.word_index) + 1,
    output_dim=embedding_dim,
    input_shape=(sequences.shape[1],)
)

model = Sequential(
    [
        embedding_layer,
        LSTM(6, activation='tanh'),
        RepeatVector(sequences.shape[1]),
        LSTM(6, activation='tanh', return_sequences=True),
        Dense(embedding_dim)
    ]
)

model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()

y = embedding_layer(sequences)
model.fit(sequences, y, epochs=10, batch_size=1)

y_hat = model.predict(sequences)
```

Comment: thanks for the tip @MarcoCerliani! i'll definitely have a look at that.